# Do I need to `mysql_upgrade --verbose -u root -p` each time when `source backup.sql`?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mariadb

I am upgrading `mysql 5.1` to `mysql 5.5` in `centos 7` server.

As time limit,I only `mysqldump` and `source` several small database to `mysql 5.5`,and then `mysql_upgrade --verbose -u root -p`,everything is ok.

Several days later, I import a big database `db3` to `mysql 5.5`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql -u root -p < db3.sql
Enter password: 
[root@localhost ~]# mysql_upgrade --verbose -u root -p
Enter password: 
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.60-MariaDB, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
[root@localhost ~]# mysql_upgrade --verbose --force -u root -p
Enter password: 
Looking for 'mysql' as: mysql
Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: mysqlcheck
Phase 1/4: Fixing views
```

Pls notice `This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.60-MariaDB, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade`.
Do I need to run `mysql_upgrade --verbose -u root -p` again?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_upgrade` *may* or may not be needed.  It is useful after you upgrade the *server* version.

In some cases (I don't remember 5.1 to 5.5), there were changes to datatypes that necessitated "fixing" the schema and the data in table(s) affected by such.

If you are dumping from the same *major* version that you are loading into, there should be no need for running `mysql_upgrade`.

If you have clues of what it changed, we can discuss further.

(Note:  Even 5.5 is getting rather "old".  I hope you will be moving forward soon.)

As I understand it, `mysql_upgrade` leaves a file behind after it runs.  The file tells it "I have upgraded to X.YY.ZZ, so I don't need to run again".

Apparently, that file (on your machine) says that it has upgrated to 5.5, so it should not be needed again.

Do you have any symptoms of things not working 'right'?  If so, let's approach the question from there.

Comment: I revised question, I get notice as :`This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.5.60-MariaDB, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade`.

Comment: @kittygirl - I added to my answer.